# Remove Unrecognized Characters Instead of Storing Question Marks

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a database that stores data as UTF-8, but sometimes some data (outside of my control) is added with unrecognized characters which are stored as question marks (`?`). Is there any way to configure MySQL to remove those characters instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe solving the problem instead of working around it will be the better solution. if you just remove the question marks, the stored data wouldn't be so ugly as it#s now, but it will still be wrong (wrong = not exactly the data the user wanted to save).

this problem sounds like you've missed to specify a character encoding somewhere, so that the client's default settings are used (you havn't said wich exactly are the clients - maybe the users browser?) wich seems to be utf-8 or something compatible most times - but sometimes there's a clint with an exotic default charset wich makes you run into problems.

to solve this, simply make sure you've set character encoding to **utf-8 everywere**:

- tell MySQL to use utf-8. to do this, add this to your my.cnf:

  > ```
  > collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
  > character_set_server = utf8
  > ```
- before interacting with mysql, send this two querys:

  > ```
  > SET NAMES 'utf8';
  > CHARSET 'utf8';
  > ```

  or, alternatively, let php do this afteropening the connection:

  > ```
  > mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn);
  > ```
- set UTF-8 as the default charset for your database

  > ```
  > CREATE DATABASE `my_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
  > ```
- do the same for tables:

  > ```
  > CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  >   -- ...
  > ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
  > ```
- assuming the client is a browser, serve your content as utf-8 and the the correct header:

  > ```
  > header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  > ```

  to be really sure the browser understands, add a meta-tag:

  > ```
  > <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  > ```
- and, last but not least, tell the browser to submit forms using utf-8

  > ```
  > <form accept-charset="utf-8" ...>
  > ```

Comment: I am indexing other websites and sometimes even the UTF-8 sites have some characters are turned into question marks by MySQL. Does that even make sense? Does that mean it is a problem with the way I'm processing it or could it mean it is an error on their side? (The characters are displayed properly on their site, BTW.)

Comment: if the characters are displayed correctly on their sites, the problem seems to be on yours. do you get `?`s from sites using utf-8 themself or just from the ones using other charsets? if the problem happens on the other ones, make sure you're converting the content from the other charset to utf-8 before inserting into your database.